# Angular Material Multi Select dropdown with Option groups select only one item from each group?

Tags: javascript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to implement multiple select dropdown with options group and user able to select only one item from each group in multiple select dropdown.

```
<mat-form-field class="kb-article-filter-field" floatLabel="never">
                <mat-select name="searchSettings" multiple>
                  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of textSearchTypes" [label]="group.name">
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of group.options" [value]="option.value">
                      {{option}}
                    </mat-option>
                  </mat-optgroup>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>

textSearchTypes = [
    {
        name: 'searchName', 
        options: [
            { name: 'test', value: 'test' },
            { name: 'test1', value: 'test1' },
            { name: 'test2', value: 'test2' }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'searchId', 
        options: [
            {name:'testId', value:'testId'},
            {name:'testId1', value:'testId1'},
            {name:'testId2', value:'testId1'}
        ]
    }
  ];
```

Could any one please help how to select only one item from each group in multi select dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Attach a valueChange event to your mat-select. In the method that you attach you do the following:

- If there is an item selected in your group, disable other items in the group.
- If there is no item selected in your group, enable all items in the group.

```js
selectionChanged() {
  // Perform enable / disable for your options
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field class="kb-article-filter-field" floatLabel="never">
  <mat-select name="searchSettings" multiple (valueChange)=selectionChanged()>
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of textSearchTypes" [label]="group.name">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of group.options" [value]="option.value">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```